# How to capture packages via both eth0 and lo at the same time?

Tags: tcpdump

There are two net interfaces on my pc.

```
netstat -i
Kernel Interface table
Iface   MTU Met   RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
eth0       1500 0     27186      0      0 0         20784      0      0      0 BMRU
lo        65536 0     42025      0      0 0         42025      0      0      0 LRU
```

Packages via lo can captured by.

```
sudo tcpdump  -i lo
```

Packages via eth0 can captured by.

```
sudo tcpdump  -i eth0
```

How to capture packages via both eth0 and lo at the same time?
**sudo tcpdump  -i eth0 -i lo** can not work.
**sudo tcpdump  -i eth0 -i lo** = **sudo tcpdump  -i eth0**=**sudo tcpdump**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your kernel supports it, you can run `tcpdump -i any`, but that will capture on ***all*** interfaces, and not just on the `lo` and `eth0` interfaces.  Also, according to the [`tcpdump` man page](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html), *"... captures on the ''any'' device will not be done in promiscuous mode."*, so if you need to place the NIC in promiscuous mode in order to capture your traffic of interest, this solution may not work for you.  In that case, you could:

- Start 2 separate instances of `tcpdump`, one capturing on `lo` and the other capturing on `eth0`.  If you write the packets to separate files, you can use a tool such as [`mergecap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/mergecap.html) to merge them together afterward.
- Use [`dumpcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html) or [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) instead, either of which can capture on multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Another option you can try out is to run tcpdump process on two interface parallely, like

sudo tcpdump  -i lo &
sudo tcpdump  -i eth0 &

& will make it run in background

With this the issue  of flooding of packet caused by "any" option can be moved out also, you can achieve the intention of capturing only on two interface as mentioned

Answer (score 1):

from https://serverfault.com/questions/805006/tcpdump-on-multiple-interfaces

> The way I would approach this is to dump on each interface to a
> separate file and then merge them. The any interface also includes lo
> traffic which can pollute the capture.
>
> This also allows for analysis of the packet streams per interface
> without complex filtering.
>
> I would capture in 3 terminals or by backgrounding the command with &
>
> The flags -nn turns off dns resolution for speed, -s 0 saves the full
> packet and -w writes to a file.
>
> tcpdump -i wan0 -nn -s 0 -w wan0.dump tcpdump -i wan1 -nn -s 0 -w
> wan1.dump tcpdump -i lan0 -nn -s 0 -w lan0.dump I would then merge the
> files with the mergecap command from wireshark:
>
> mergecap -w merged.dump wan0.dump wan1.dump lan0.dump